# How do implement customMenuBuilder into selectable text class

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

```
SelectableText('text',
cursorColor: Colors.red,
showCursor: true,
style: const TextStyle(
fontSize: 14,
fontWeight:
FontWeight.w500,
color: Colors.black))
```

I initially used toolbar options in the code, but now it has been deprecated and I'm trying to implement customMenuBuilder into the code so as to copy the text that would appear in the text field.

Comment: Can you show us more code  or de desired result and the error you're getting ?

Comment: Alright will do that